# Ethernet Doesn't Have a valid IP configuration - Able to connect through wireless

Tags: windows-10, internet-connection, windows-error-reporting

I am unable to access my internet through on my PC through Ethernet and when I try troubleshooting it says - Problem Found - "Ethernet" doesn't have a valid IP configuration.

I tried various methods to solve the error but without any success. Some methods I used are as follows:

1. Disabling Fast Boot
2. Resetting my Router manually
3. Going to Command Prompt and typing "ipconfig /release" which gives the message - " An error occurred while releasing Interface Ethernet : An address has not yet been associated with the network endpoint."
4. Going to Command Prompt and typing "ipconfig /renew" which gives the message - "An error occurred while renewing interface Ethernet : An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permission"

In above steps I used Command Prompt with Administrative Privileges.

I suspect that my PC may have been infected by a virus which is blocking my internet.

Note that I am able to connect to the Internet through Wireless Connection on my mobile device (on which I am accessing this site)

Kindly help

Comment: I suggest you do a firewall reset.

Comment: @jdwolf just reset my firewall and restarted my pc. Still no connection

Comment: Go to Windows firewall in control panel and on the left is restore defaults

Comment: @jdwolf did that. No effect

Comment: What antivirus do you have?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was installing Bit Defender Total Security on my PC when it prompted me to uninstall the other antivirus (Avast Premier). I uninstalled Avast and restarted my computer and that's when it all started. Now I am unable to install BitDefender on my PC since it requires Internet Connection to download. So at this point, I have no Antivirus

Comment: Run your computer in safe mode with networking and see if that works. I also think that bit defender is at least partially installed

Comment: Tried to reset firewall in safe mode. No impact. Is the partially installed Bit defender a problem? If yes how should I resolve that ?

Comment: I meant that try to see if networking works in safe mode with networking.

Comment: No. I couldn't access the network in safe mode with networking.

Comment: Please help. I even tried to reset my Windows keeping all my personal files. It temporary solved the problem. But after 6-7 hour of use the problem came back.

Comment: For me, this error was because the DHCP IP address lease has expired, and the DHCP server isn't issuing a new one. This creates a conflict between what it thinks is your IP and what the DHCP server is allowing. Restart the router.